# iOs Modal transitions like Mailboxapp

Tags: ios, modal-dialog, transition, uipageviewcontroller

I started developing an iOs app for my employers some days ago. They would like to get a transition flow like the MailBox App. I already figured out how to do the split menu on the left but I can't figure out how to do the modal transition that is coming from the back when you tap an e-mail. Once you are in an e-mail you can slide back to the inbox. Is it possible that this is achieved by a PageViewController ? If not does anyone know how to achieve an effect like that ?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also looking for some modal transition animations and found those two frameworks:
https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFFadeBackModalAnimation
https://github.com/ucu072/HCPushBackAnimation

Answer (score 0):

I think you are referring to custom controls which you might find here: http://www.cocoacontrols.com or on Github. If not the same you will find something similar or you will have to create it yourself :)

Comment: Well, thank you for that great website. It will definitely imrpove my app, even if I don't find something like mailboxapp